# wp_register_script only works with 2 arguments

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, child-theming

I am trying to add a custom JavaScript file in my child theme. After a few hours, I finally got it working with the following code:

```
wp_register_script( 'resources-page',
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/js/resources_page.js'
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'resources-page' );
```

I don't understand why this would fail (the `resources_page.js` doesn't get called at all) if I do it like this (with the rest of the params):

```
wp_register_script( 'resources-page',
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/js/resources_page.js',
  array( 'jquery '),
  NULL,
  true
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'resources-page' );
```

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, packing the whole thing into a function which you then put into an action hook:

```
function register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('resources-page',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/layout/js/resources_page.js',
    array( 'jquery'),
    NULL,
    true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'resources-page' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts');
```